# Access VBA SQL Syntax Error (Missing Operator)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having an issue getting a SQL statement to open a recordset correctly.  I am receiving a syntax error saying I am missing an operator.  This happened after I added in a CASE statement to try to get the average for only numbers greater than zero.  Below is the SQL string that I am building

```
 SELECT AVG (([t1].[MET_Value] / 147000) * [t1].[LMP]) AS RW, 
                   COUNT ([t1].[MetTime]) AS METcnt, 
                   AVG ([t1].[MET_Value]/147000) AS AvgCF, 
                   AVG(CASE WHEN [t1].[LMP] > 0 THEN ([t1].[MET_Value] / 147000) * [t1].[LMP] ELSE NULL END) AS Floor0Avg 
        FROM
            (SELECT [Data].[Local_Datetime],
                    [Data].[Node_ID],
                    [Data].[LMP],
                    [Data].[5810] AS MET_Value, 
                    [MetData].[Local_Datetime] AS MetTime 
             FROM [Data] INNER JOIN 
                  [MetData] ON [Data].[Local_Datetime] LIKE [MetData].[Local_Datetime] 
            WHERE [Node_ID] = 746200 AND [LMP] <> -999999 AND [Data].[Local_Datetime] BETWEEN #9/2/2015# AND #9/1/2016#)
        as t1 GROUP BY Node_ID;
```

This works if I take out the AVG(CASE WHEN ..) but I can't seem to get it to work with it so I am assuming that is where the problem is.

I have been trying to get this to work but can't find what is wrong. Please let me know if you see my error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by replacing this line if it's working by removing this from the code.

```
AVG(CASE WHEN [t1].[LMP] > 0 THEN (([t1].[MET_Value] / 147000) * [t1].[LMP]) ELSE NULL END) AS Floor0Avg
```

Comment: `Case` isn't available in MS Access. You need to use `Switch`

Answer (score 0):

Ryan W got it.
Swapped

```
AVG(CASE WHEN [t1].[LMP] > 0 THEN ([t1].[MET_Value] / 147000) * [t1].[LMP] ELSE NULL END) AS Floor0Avg
```

for

```
AVG(Switch([t1].[LMP] > 0,([t1].[MET_Value]/147000)*[t1].[LMP])) AS Floor0Avg
```

and it appears to be working.